# How do I disable all non-core modules in Magento 2? (in 1 step)

Tags: module, extensions

Suppose I want to go back to the code state where only M2 core modules are active.

question: How do I disable all non-core modules in Magento 2? (in 1 step)

Answer (score 3):

*it will find & disable all modules except which one start with Magento_*

```
$ php bin/magento module:status | grep -v Magento | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

*To disable all module for particular vendor, you could use something like this*

```
$ php bin/magento module:status | grep VendorName_ | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

The differences is one with grep -v Magento and the other is grep VendorName_

check this and let me know if any issue

Comment: `grep -v List` will skip any module that has "List" in its name. So, it's better to use `grep -v -e "^List\s.*$"` instead. This will only skip the line which has "List" followed by a space, e.g. "List of disabled modules", "List of enabled modules".

Answer (score 0):

One option is to execute

```
php bin/magento module:disable $(php bin/magento module:status | grep -vE '^Magento|List of enabled modules:|List of disabled modules:|None|^$')
```

It will grep all none core modules and pass them as a list to the disable command

https://www.michiel-gerritsen.com/disabling-non-magento-modules-magento-2/